# How to get \CodeAfter contents in nicematrix to typeset as background?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nicematrix

I am trying to post the contents in `\CodeAfter` in `nicematrix` as background. I generally want results similar to what we get with `\cellcolor`, but with the flexibility of `tikzpicture` environment

[image]

In the above image, we see that `C_1_1` is not visible

```
\documentclass[amsthm]{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{hvlines, rules/color=[gray]{0.95}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin]
        C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}
        \\
        C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}
        \\
        C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}
        \CodeAfter
        \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
            \draw[IndianRed1, fill=IndianRed1!11] (1-|1) rectangle (2-|2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

In principle, it is possible to typeset background for tikz nodes

```
\documentclass[amsthm]{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    
    \node[align=flush left, inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=1pt, outer xsep=0pt, outer ysep=0pt, anchor=base] (basmah) {text};
    
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        
        \fill[Ivory1, opacity=0.75] (basmah.south west) rectangle (basmah.north east);
        
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably use `\CodeBefore` if you want to add background color to cells. The background needs to be drawn before the cells, but the border afterwards. So, I fear there is no other way than to split things up and use both `\CodeBefore` and `\CodeAfter`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht. I think it is still possible to typeset background with `\CodeAfter`

Comment: As far as I understand the mechanism of `\CodeAfter`, it executes the code *after* the cells have been typeset. This means that even if you place things on the `background` layer in the `tikzpicture`, this layer is still in front of the cells, because the whole `tikzpicture` is typeset after the cells have already been typeset.

Answer (score 2):

You have tow possibilities:

1. It's possible, as suggested by Jasper Habicht, to split things up and use both `\CodeBefore` and `\CodeAfter`.
2. It's also possible to use a `\Block` (of course, you have to put the instruction in the cell and maybe, you will consider that it will clutter your main array).

```
\documentclass[amsthm]{book}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{hvlines, rules/color=[gray]{0.95}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin]
        \Block[fill=IndianRed1!11,draw = IndianRed1,line-width=1pt]{}{C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}
        \\
        C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}
        \\
        C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: The fact that it is cluttered is why I want to typeset the rectangle with `\CodeAfter`. Is it possible to try including such request as a feature?

Comment: OK. I will try to add a new feature in `nicematrix`.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you want to do it exclusively with `\CodeBefore` and `\CodeAfter`,here is it:

[image: CodeAfter and CodeBefore]

```
\documentclass[amsthm]{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NiceMatrixOptions{hvlines, rules/color=[gray]{0.95}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin]
    \CodeBefore
        \rectanglecolor{IndianRed1!11}{1-1}{1-1}
    \Body
        C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}
        \\
        C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}
        \\
        C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}} & C_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}
    \CodeAfter
        \tikz \draw[thick,IndianRed1] (1-|1) rectangle (2-|2);
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```